# Uniform convergence of ${f_n(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g_n(t)}dt$ where $g_n(x)=\sin^2(x+\frac{1}{n})$.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I need to prove that $${f_n(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g_n(t)}dt$$ where $g_n(x)=\sin^2(x+\frac{1}{n})$ is uniformly convergent on

1. $[0,\infty)$
2. $[0,1]$

How can I do this? Is it correct to argue that if $g_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent then $f_n$ is also uniformly convergent? How can I find some $N$ s.t $\forall n>N$ it is true? Any help please.

**Edit**
So I compute $f_n(x)$ and got

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\frac{\sin2x}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Why not *compute* $f_n(x)$? Anyway, the argument that if $g_n$ is uniformly convergent then $f_n$ is also uniformly convergent is frankly wrong on an unbounded interval such that $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: You mean I should compute $f_n=\int_{0}^{x}\sin^2(t+1/n)dt$? @Did

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Next step is to recall the definition of a sequence of functions being uniformly convergent on some interval...

Comment: so what ever I got by taking limit to $f_n$ is now my $f(x)$ right and now I have to apply the definition of uniform convergence and show $<\epsilon$ @Did

Comment: yes thanks @S.Panja-1729